# In a Makefile, how can I fetch and assign a git commit hash to a variable?

Tags: git, makefile

A **make all** clones the git repo.  I want to know what the commit hash is and assign the git commit hash to a variable which can be used later in the Makefile

e.g.

```
all: download
      echo '$(GIT_COMMIT)'

download:
      cd buildarea && git clone git@github.com:proj/project.git
      $(eval GIT_COMMIT = $(shell cd buildarea/project && git log -l --pretty=format:"%H"))
      echo '$(GIT_COMMIT)'
```

Comment: 1) How do you obtain the hash *without* Make (i.e. using git directly), and 2) are you willing to store the hash in a file?

Comment: 1) I use a "git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H"  2) Is that really the only way?

Comment: What's your actual question (since the question subject is answered in the full question itself)? How is your code failing you? There are _multiple_ ways to get the hash of the most recent commit, and yours is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example fails.   Nothing is assigned to GIT_COMMIT

Comment: No, that is not the only way, but it is the simplest. There is no clean way for a rule to obtain information from its prerequisite rule, Make simply isn't designed to do that. There are a few different approaches, but each works better for some cases that for others. If you tell us what you're actually trying to do, maybe we can help.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out the the head of the git repo that was downloaded, assign the hash to a variable, and then use the variable later on in the make.

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to do that, but I'm reasonably sure that any one that I post will not be what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about use shell function and 2 targets for it?

```
all: download getver

getver: VER=$(shell cd buildarea/project && git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H")
getver:
        @echo GIT_COMMIT=$(VER)

download:
        mkdir -p buildarea && cd buildarea && git@github.com:proj/project.git
```

Comment: The only mod I need to make was `getver: $(eval GIT_COMMIT=$(shell cd buildarea/project && git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H")`

Comment: I was confused by this "prerequisite" of the form `VER=$(...)`. For future visitors: this is a [target-specific variable value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way that make evaluates the target the `git clone` executes *after* `$(shell)`, so `cd` tries to move to a directory that doesn't exist yet. What you can do is simply perform the whole act in a single `$(shell)` call.

```
all: download
      echo '$(GIT_COMMIT)'

download:
      $(eval GIT_COMMIT = $(shell git clone git@github.com:proj/project.git buildarea/project && cd buildarea/project && git rev-parse HEAD))
      echo '$(GIT_COMMIT)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also work if you trigger the `make git_sha` under subdirectory:

```
GIT_SHA_FETCH := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c 1-8)
export GIT_SHA=$(GIT_SHA_FETCH)

git_sha:
    @echo GIT_SHA is $(GIT_SHA)
```