# How do I safe git information in a file using GNU-make variables

Tags: gnu-make

I want to save some git information in a textfile, which I want to put in the src folder of my project.

In case branch Master is checked out, I only want the date of the latest commit. If any other branch is checked out I want the date and the name of the branch like so:

`date-branchname`

This is my code:

```
src/version2.txt:
    DATE=$(shell git log -1 --date=format:"%Y.%m.%d" --format="%ad")
    BRANCH=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    
ifeq ($(BRANCH), 'Master')
    $(DATE) > $@
else
    DATE+='-'
    DATE+=$(BRANCH)
    $(DATE) > $@
    
endif
```

I'm new to GNU make and quite confused with its syntax.
I assume my ifeq/else blocks are working fine, since I checked printing a dummy text to the `version.txt` file while having the Master or some other branch checked out.
I also saw my commands to get the date or the branch are ok, since I can put them to the textfile like so:

```sh
git log -1 --date=format:"%Y.%m.%d" --format="%ad" > $@
```

Only when I want to use variables, it seems the variable is empty, for example

```
$(DATE) > $@
```

seems to print an empty string to the textfile.
Also, I don't know if my way of creating the DATE-BRANCH output is correct at all.
I've spent ages trying and would really appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712972/in-a-makefile-how-can-i-fetch-and-assign-a-git-commit-hash-to-a-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot create GNU make variables inside recipes and use them later in the GNU make file because GNU make first parses whole file and then runs recipes
2. You cannot use GNU make `ifeq`s inside recipes
3. `%` in command lines may cause problems in Windows, so I've added a workaround for it in the following code (skip it if your Makefile should work only for Unix-like systems)
4. `'` should not be used in `ifeq`s constants (GNU make reads it literaly)
5. `src/version2.txt` does not depend on anything and therefore will not be regenerated by GNU make (if it already exists), consider `.PHONY` for the target

Try this:

```
BRANCH:=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  P:=%%
else
  P:=%
endif

.PHONY : src/version2.txt

ifeq ($(BRANCH),master)
src/version2.txt :
    git log -1 --date=format:"$PY.$Pm.$Pd" --format="$Pad" >$@
else
src/version2.txt :
    git log -1 --date=format:"$PY.$Pm.$Pd" --format="$Pad-$(BRANCH)" >$@
endif
```

Note that `BRANCH` will be computed each time you run `make` even if the `src/version2.txt` should not be regenerated.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, or you may ask additional questions if you need some clarifications or more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Point 1. , 2. 4. and 5. are really helpfull for basic understanding on how to do stuff like this.
I just need to ask: does GNU try to interpret 
 git log -1 --date=format:"%%Y.%%m.%%d" --format="%%ad" 
part by part using its own syntax since this is a shell command? I ask because your solution does print %ad, not the date. If i remove the escaping "%" it works as intended.

Comment: I will close the question in a second, just for completness and others to take advantage of your help i want to point out there is a typo that needs to be fixed to make it work.
--format="%ad-$(BRANCH)" needs to be --format="%ad"-$(BRANCH)

Comment: GNU make preprocesses each recipe line (at least because it substitutes its variables), but it seems like `%` actually should not be escaped in unix. Before I sent the answer I've tested my code on Windows and there percent symbol should be doubled for some reason (interferences with Batch files' `%`-variables I guess). Thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed my answer.